# asp.net core 2.0 can not write cookie in safari browser

Tags: c#, .net, safari, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new in .net core.
This is a shopify app and load on shopify's iframe.
It works great in all browsers accept `Safari`.
Because Safari dont give permission to write cookie on browser.
One solution is changing the browser setting.But most of client will not do that.
I have to do it pragmatically.

Comment: You can't change the browser's settings to allow you to write a cookie programatically; at least not without raising some red flags. If their browser doesn't allow you to store cookies, then simply don't rely on cookies. Find an alternative way of storing things. It's hard to give you an actual solution though when we don't have actual information or code.

Comment: i want to write cookie forcefully on browser.is there any way?

Comment: If the browser doesn't let you, the browser doesn't let you.

Comment: This is basic client-server interaction. The HTTP protocol is designed such that both the server and client operate on their own terms. The client can only make a request; the server decides whether or not and how to respond. Likewise, the server simply sends a response, and it's 100% up to the client what to do with that response. In other words, you (the server in this scenario) cannot force the browser (the client) to do *anything*. If it is configured to not allow cookies, then cookies will not be set. Period.

Comment: Just to elucidate a bit more. "Setting" a cookie is simply returning a "Set-Cookie" header as part of the response. The server doesn't *actually* set anything. The client (web browser), reads this header, and typically will set the cookie. However, since the client here has cookies disabled, it will then simply ignore that response header. All the server can do is request that the cookie be set, it doesn't actually have access to the client to do anything itself.

Comment: i searched and found something call p3p.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can be useful.

It was extremely useful for me to read this discussion :
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2595

The changes made to my service ..

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
});
```